How to define unique types in a header file to be used across multiple translation units and avoid ODR errors?
In the below example (which compiles fine with GCC) I need to make sure that non-static members value1 and value2 have unique types and once the header containing the struct Foo is included in multiple TUs, it shouldn't cause an ODR violation. I am facing an ODR error in my project in linkage stage since I've used decltype( []{} ) in a header file which means every TU that includes it will have its own uniquely-typed lambda.
Hence I used inline static inside struct Foo here to try and fix this issue.
The minimal example:
#include <type_traits>

// Util.hpp
template <typename UniqueType = decltype( []{} )>
inline constexpr UniqueType uniquely_typed_variable { UniqueType { } };

// Foo.hpp
struct Foo
{
    inline static constexpr auto unused_var1 { uniquely_typed_variable<> };
    inline static constexpr auto unused_var2 { uniquely_typed_variable<> };

    using MyType1 = decltype( unused_var1 );
    using MyType2 = decltype( unused_var2 );
    static_assert( not std::is_same_v<MyType1, MyType2> );

    MyType1 value1;
    MyType2 value2;
};


// A few .cpp files using "Foo.hpp"
// #include "Foo.hpp"

int main( )
{
    [[ maybe_unused ]] Foo foo {};
}

Is the above a correct way of doing this? Or is there a more elegant way of achieving such behavior?

Can you use a lambda as the unique unused_vars?  I.e. inline static constexpr auto unused_var1 = []{};  Actually, it seems this is what you are doing, in a more roundabout way....

@TobySpeight Yeah, maybe. Essentialy the two members must have unique types but still be consistent in all TUs.

Ah, I misunderstood - I thought you needed Foo to be different in each TU so that they're distinct.  Exactly backwards from the reality.  I should have realised that you'd have just used an anonymous namespace in that case.

@TobySpeight Like this link?

What do you even mean by "unique type that's consistent across all TUs" -- or more precisely, why can't you just use class UniqueType {} and be done with it? In C++, every type is unique, and consistent across all TUs...

The other thing that occurs to me that might be sufficient is to use UniqueType<int> with __LINE__ as the template parameter.  That's predictable, but generates distinct types.

@TobySpeight No. Foo must be the same exact thing in all TUs. My previous approach made the linker cry. Then I noticed that these lambdas are different in each TU that includes Foo!!

A solution:
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

inline constexpr std::tuple uniquely_typed_values { []{}, []{} };

struct Foo
{
    using MyType1 = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( std::get<0>( uniquely_typed_values ) )>;
    using MyType2 = std::remove_reference_t<decltype( std::get<1>( uniquely_typed_values ) )>;
    static_assert( not std::is_same_v<MyType1, MyType2> );

    MyType1 value1;
    MyType2 value2;
};


int main( )
{
    [[ maybe_unused ]] Foo foo {};
}


I think this is a compiler bug. It seems to have been spotted in this question: Do lambda expressions that appear in different definitions of a same entity produce the same closure type? Clang and GCC both seem to treat uniquely_typed_variable<decltype([]{})> as having a no linkage/a local type.
Since you are only using the lambda for uniqueness, you can emulate it yourself:
template<int, typename...> struct unique_type {};
template<int N, typename... T> inline constexpr unique_type<N, T...> uniquely_typed_variable{};

struct Foo
{
    inline static constexpr auto unused_var1 { uniquely_typed_variable<0, Foo> };
    inline static constexpr auto unused_var2 { uniquely_typed_variable<1, Foo> };

    using MyType1 = decltype( unused_var1 );
    using MyType2 = decltype( unused_var2 );
    static_assert( not std::is_same_v<MyType1, MyType2> );

    MyType1 value1;
    MyType2 value2;
};

Which is similar to how compilers should number lambda types in classes anyway.
It also seems like your problem can be solved by just declaring two types:
struct Foo {
    struct {} value1;
    struct {} value2;

    using MyType1 = decltype(value1);
    using MyType2 = decltype(value2);
    static_assert(not std::is_same_v<MyType1, MyType2>);

    // Or just
    struct MyType1 {} value1;
    struct MyType2 {} value2;
    static_assert(not std::is_same_v<MyType1, MyType2>);
};

And extending to other situations with private: struct UniqueType1 {}; public: /* Use UniqueType1, different from all other types */
